# Why am I not able to print the last character in below code?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to take sentence as an input from the user in the below code.
eg.
Input -

9

do or die

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the length of the sentence: ";
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();
    char array[n+1]; 
    cin.getline(array,n);
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<array[7]<<endl;
    cout<<array[8]<<endl;
```

While printing the array[7], I am getting 'i' as my output, but while printing array[8] I am expecting 'e' as my output but I did not get anything as an output.
I have declared character array of size (n+1), which means array[n] should be null character but why array[8] is coming out to be null character?

Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Comment: "which means array[n] should be null character" why? Where in your code do you set `array[n]` to null ?

Comment: BTW: Creating your array this way is no valid C++. Use a size which is known and const at compile time, or use dynamic allocation or vector. Some compilers may allow what you are doing, but it is no valid C++ and others may not compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::istream::getline(char* s, streamsize n):

1. Extracts characters from the stream as unformatted input and stores them into s as a c-string.
2. n is the maximum number of characters to write to s, **including** the terminating null character.

If you want to read your 9 characters of the sentence, not only your buffer needs to be 10 characters long, but also n in getline needs to be 10.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the actual problem is addressed by @SKCoder, so I just want to add that input handling works better with `std::string` and I changed the code accordingly:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    size_t n;
    std::cout<<"Enter the length of the sentence: ";
    std::cin>>n;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout<<str.substr(str.length()-2, 2)<<"\n";
    std::cout << (str.length() != n? "length is wrong": "length is correct") << "\n";
}
```

I usually don't use `using namespace std;` to avoid namespace clashes, but in this case it may make sense.
Using a string, you don't need the length anymore, so you can use it to test valid input.